# Compiling spellfix for sqlite3

Tags: c++, gcc, sqlite

I needed wanted to build "did you mean this?" feature to my website. I'm using sqlite3 and learned that i can use spellfix module to order tables via levenstein.

I downloaded [source code of sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/2013/sqlite-src-3071700.zip) and compiled spellfix.c (it's inside /ext/misc/) like this:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -Wall -I/tmp/sqlite-src-3071700/ spellfix.c -o spellfix
```

It compiles successfuly but when i load it into sqlite:

```
sqlite> .load ./spellfix
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: ./spellfix: undefined symbol: sqlite3_extension_init
```

I really have very few knowledge about compiling c programs. Did i do some mistake about compiling or something else is happened? What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the sqlite init function is missing.  There is a discussion here http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/SQLite-version-3-7-16-td67776.html

I added the following code at the top.

```
static int spellfix1Register(sqlite3 *db); 

int sqlite3_extension_init(sqlite3 *db, char ** pxErrMsg, const sqlite3_api_routines *pApi){
    SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT2(pApi);
    return spellfix1Register(db);
}
```

Also needed the following since I couldn't pull in the headers for the sqlite3_stricmp function without creating additional problems:

```
int sqlite3_stricmp(const char *zLeft, const char *zRight){
    return strcasecmp(zLeft, zRight);
}
```

And needed this too:

```
#define SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL      (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT | (5<<8))
```

Then it compiled and seemed to function correctly.

Comment: which Code did you add these extentions to? is it spellfix?